# Ajax not firing on submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to create a form that has an action to a URL. But it requires ajax submission first and then it should submit to the action.

It should send me an email (within the newsletter.php).

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function () {
    $("#signup").on('submit', function( e, response ) {
        if (response.errors == false) {
            $.ajax({
                type : 'GET',
                url : 'newsletter.php',
                data: {
                    name : $('#os0').val(),
                    email: $('#os1').val()
                },
                success : function(data) {
                    $('#subscribe').submit();
                },
                error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    // error handling
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<form name="signup" id="signup" action="" method="GET">
    <input type="text" id="os0" name="Email" />
    <input class="text" id="os1" type="text" name="cd_FULLNAME" />
    <input type="Submit" name="Submit" id="subscribe" value="Subscribe" />
</form>
```

Comment: This will be neverending loop.

Comment: Where is your submit handler supposed to get a variable named `response` from …?

Comment: What is `response` doing here? It would be `undefined`. check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/karthikr12/c2m09dsk/ (has the prevent default action )

Comment: @karthikr it doesnt seem to be working, only response is undefined.

Comment: @karthikr - and this is why his "`if ( response.errors`" throws an error and further code never executes

Comment: @Igor Can you please elaborate? what is the best way to proceed forward? should i remove the response parameter and remove the `if (response.errors == false` element?

Comment: Sorry - I had pasted the wrong fiddle link. http://jsfiddle.net/karthikr12/c2m09dsk/1/ Is what i meant.. anyways.. looks like you got what you were looking for. You might want to prevent the default action too... (e.preventDefault())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function () {
    $("#signup").on('submit', function( e, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url : 'newsletter.php',
            data: {
                name : $('#os0').val(),
                email: $('#os1').val()
            },
            success : function(data) {
                $("#signup")[0].submit();
            },
            error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // error handling
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Note the difference between `$("#signup")submit();` and `$("#signup")[0].submit();`.